# Duplicate ID error - Don't understand other explanations

Tags: apex, salesforce-id, trigger

I've been working at this project for two days now.
I've read this: [List Exception Duplicate id error](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53341/list-exception-duplicate-id-error)
And this: [Avoiding 'Duplicate ID in List' Error in Update Trigger](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/6169/avoiding-duplicate-id-in-list-error-in-update-trigger)

I try to resolve it as best as I can before posting, but I'm at a total loss.

I tried to resolve the issue using sets, but couldn't get it to work, or would get errors saying that the set type was incorrect and it needed to be a list. This was confusing because I had also read a forum post on the Salesforce dev forum saying that Sets are not iteratable.

I cannot for the life of me figure out what else to do to get it to stop throwing this error:

```
execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.ListException: Duplicate id in list:
```

I am extremely confused. Could someone help me figure out where I'm screwing up, and ELI5 me on the explanation so I can remember how to avoid this issue in the future? I feel like it's something small, that once I grasp the concept I will likely slap my forehead.

Thanks.

```
trigger VS_Design_One_Approved_Only on VS_Design__c (after update){
   List<VS_Design__c> ul = new List<VS_Design__c>();
   for(VS_Design__c d: trigger.new){ //references our current record

    List<VS_Design__c> od = new List<VS_Design__c>([SELECT Name, Id, Account__c, Revision_Of_Design__C, Rejected_By__c FROM VS_Design__c WHERE Account__c = : d.Account__c ]);

    for(VS_Design__c ndd : od){ 
    //for loop above if right after select statement to iterate 
    //logical if condition, make sure != to d.Id
        if(d.Approved_On__c != null) {
                VS_Design__c nd = new VS_Design__c();

                nd.Id = ndd.Id;
                nd.Account__c = d.Account__c;
                nd.Revision_of_Design__c = d.id;
                nd.Structural_Info__c = d.Structural_Info__c;
                nd.Opportunity__c = d.Opportunity__c;
                nd.OwnerId = d.OwnerId;
                nd.Status__c = 'Closed';
                nd.Status_Reason__c = 'Revision Required';

                ul.add(nd);

        } 
    }
    update ul;
}
```

}

EDIT/UPDATE - 6/9/2016

So after taking the advice offered, (a big thanks to @LaceySnr for his advice, and to everyone else who offered help), I was able to get it working and kind of make sense of what I was doing. I also added a condition to my IF statement for matching, so instead of just matching by ID, I also required it to make sure Approved_On wasn't equal to null. As part of iterating I changed the field to null, so the next time the records ran around, it wouldn't add it to the list a second time.

In particular I couldn't get the query to work outside the initial trigger for loop.

I do use more descriptive variable names in my own work, but my manager was using short ones like this and I wanted to keep the code similar to his.

I know it's not as clean as it should be, but it's at least working. I'm hoping to refine it to make it as clean as possible, and would request, and appreciate all advice offered on what my result was.

Thanks!

```
trigger VS_Design_One_Approved_Only on VS_Design__c (after update){
Set<Id> accountIDs = new Set<Id>();
List<VS_Design__c> ul = new List<VS_Design__c>();

for(VS_Design__c d : trigger.new){
if(d.Approved_On__c != null) {
    accountIDs.add(d.Account__c);
    List<VS_Design__c> od = [SELECT Name, Id, Approved_On__c, Type__c, Account__c, Revision_Of_Design__C, Rejected_By__c 
                            FROM VS_Design__c 
                            WHERE Account__c IN : accountIds];

    for(VS_Design__c nd : od){
        if(d.Id != nd.Id && nd.Approved_On__c != null){

        VS_Design__c toUp = new VS_Design__c();

        toUp.Id = nd.Id;
        toUp.Status__c = 'Closed';
        toUp.Status_Reason__c = 'Revision Required';
        toUp.Revision_of_Design__c = d.Id;
        toUp.Account__c = d.Account__c;
        toUp.Approved_On__c = null;
        toUp.Approved_By__c = null;

        ul.add(toUp);

    }
} 
update ul;

 }
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, there's a few things going on here to sort out.

### 1. Query in a loop

you have a query inside of a loop. There are very few good reasons to ever do that, and you should view it as an anti-pattern as it means you're more likely to hit governor limits:

```
for(VS_Design__c d: trigger.new){ //references our current record

List<VS_Design__c> od = new List<VS_Design__c>([SELECT Name, Id, Account__c, Revision_Of_Design__C, Rejected_By__c FROM VS_Design__c WHERE Account__c = : d.Account__c ]);
```

What you'd typically do here is extract the account IDs in question into a new collection, and then query, e.g.:

```
Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();

for(VS_Design__c d : trigger.new) {
  accountIds.add(d.Account__c);
}

// Note also that there is no cast needed on the query    
List<VS_Design__c> od = [SELECT Name, Id, Account__c, Revision_Of_Design__C, Rejected_By__c FROM VS_Design__c WHERE Account__c = in : accountIds]
```

### 2. Querying the same records

This is an `after update` trigger, which means your query is to bring in the records you're working with. Often you want to exclude these by building up a set (like the account IDs above) and doing a `not in` to exclude them.

### 3. Not clearing the list

Your list is never being cleared, and since you're querying by account ID that means if your trigger is run on two records which have the same Account ID then each pass through the loop will pull those records in and add them to the list, meaning at that point you've got two instances of each record in the list and hence, duplicate IDs.

### 4. Overcomplicated update

There are occasions where you create an instance of an SObject and assign an ID just to update a couple of records, but in this case you don't need to do that since you've just queried and can update those records directly (I've removed the `if` statement as that's tackled in point 5):

```
for(VS_Design__c ndd : od){ 

    ndd.Account__c = d.Account__c;
    ndd.Revision_of_Design__c = d.id;
    ndd.Structural_Info__c = d.Structural_Info__c;
    ndd.Opportunity__c = d.Opportunity__c;
    ndd.OwnerId = d.OwnerId;
    ndd.Status__c = 'Closed';
    ndd.Status_Reason__c = 'Revision Required';

    ul.add(ndd); 
}
update ul;
```

### 5. Processing overhead

No processing occurs for a record at all if `Approved_On__c` is `null`, and yet this check is only done right at the end! If you refactor this code to perform that check while gathering the account list it will save a lot of wasted processing time:

```
Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();

for(VS_Design__c d : trigger.new) {
    if(d.Approved_On__c != null) {
        accountIds.add(d.Account__c);
    }
}
```

## Summary

What's really killing you here is point number 3, but I implore you to tackle all of these points (especially number 1) rather than simply clearing the list after each update. Consider using more descriptive variable names, going out on a limb I'm guessing that `d` is design, `od` is old designs, `nd` is new design (singular) and I have no idea about `ndd` which is an element in `od`.

I'm pretty sure I know what this trigger is supposed to be doing, and I could write it out, but I think you'll get more out of it by taking another crack yourself. If you do get truly stuck then comment below and we can work it out through chat.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. I actually appreciate the explanation instead of just posting the code. I was wanting to take another crack at it with a little additional education at my disposal. I am feeling empowered, so I'm going to work at it and will report back on how it turns out, or if I need help :)

Comment: ndd was supposed to be "new design data". I don't think I understand how(VS_Design__c ndd : od) works in the for loop. I reasoned that ndd : odd meant that "in our loop, od is converted to ndd". I'm not sure what it actually means to be honest.

Comment: It's an iterator loop, for every `VS_Design__c` object in the list `od` it runs the body of the loop, with the current record available as `ndd` in this case.

If you're familiar with for loops in other languages it's a bit like this:

    `for(i = 0; i < od.length; i++)
    {
        VS_Design__c ndd = od[i];
    }`

but it's more concise.

Comment: So I've been working on this since I first commented, but I'm still a little confused. Specifically on code order. I'm not sure how to format my code... I know typically you put all your trigger code inside the initial for loop, minus list declarations and queries. But if I'm doing my query after my for loop, I'm a little lost where I go from there. Do I need another for loop? I cannot use 'trigger.new' twice right? (I'm very new to apex/coding. Only about a week at it. I have some basic JavaScript experience prior.)

Comment: You can and often do do more than one loop. One for setup, do some queries to gather required info, and then do another for processing. Most people will tell you this code shouldn't be in a trigger anyway and moved to a class, but one step at a time!

Comment: So I got it working, but the code still doesn't look that clean, and I still couldn't figure out how to work all of your instructions into what I was doing. I will add what my results where to my original post. If you don't mind, would you critique it, and possibly show me what the code should look like? Thanks!

Comment: @Genko This isn't a great place to go back and forth on this, maybe post that as a new question, or if you want I can just email you (I can get your address from your profile).

Comment: If you wouldn't mind emailing I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

instead of using list to update the records use a set and convert it back to a list.

```
List<VS_Design__c> ul = new List<VS_Design__c>();
Set<VS_Design__c> values = new Set<VS_Design__c>();
List<VS_Design__c> valuesToUpdate = new List<VS_Design__c>();


//trigger code


values.addAll(ul);
valuesToUpdate.addAll(values);
update valuesToUpdate;
```

Comment: This is helpful, thank you. I'm going to combine it with the great explanation from @LaceySnr and see if I can get this to work. Appreciate it!

Comment: This would eliminate duplicate values, but it's treating the symptom rather than the cause. Ideally you want to avoid duplicates in the first place!

Answer (score 1):

Your soql query is adding the same vs_design__c records into list multiple times, hence duplicating it.

```
trigger VS_Design_One_Approved_Only on VS_Design__c (after update){
       set<VS_Design__c> ul = new set<VS_Design__c>();
       for(VS_Design__c d: trigger.new){ //references our current record

        List<VS_Design__c> od = new List<VS_Design__c>([SELECT Name, Id, Account__c, Revision_Of_Design__C, Rejected_By__c FROM VS_Design__c WHERE Account__c = : d.Account__c ]);

        for(VS_Design__c ndd : od){ 
        //for loop above if right after select statement to iterate 
        //logical if condition, make sure != to d.Id
            if(d.Approved_On__c != null) {
                    VS_Design__c nd = new VS_Design__c();

                    nd.Id = ndd.Id;
                    nd.Account__c = d.Account__c;
                    nd.Revision_of_Design__c = d.id;
                    nd.Structural_Info__c = d.Structural_Info__c;
                    nd.Opportunity__c = d.Opportunity__c;
                    nd.OwnerId = d.OwnerId;
                    nd.Status__c = 'Closed';
                    nd.Status_Reason__c = 'Revision Required';

                    ul.add(nd);

            } 
        }
        update ul;
      }
    }
```

Other things to take care of here is to avoid soql inside for loop. instead use maps to query data outside loop and then process it.